# Remapping array elements complicated by pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to properly learn C++ and, like most, am still having a rough time with pointers etc. My naive attempt at remapping one array based on indices in another array are failing, and I suspect pointers are part of that, but I could use some eyes and advice on this code (context is microprocessor control).

Objective: given an array `CRGB leds[24]` which has been passed into my Class as `CRGB* leds` and a map of indices `uint8_t ledMap[24]`, use the map to move the data from each element of `leds[]` to a new position within the array. I'm not trying to get fancy and do a map in-place or anything and I don't care that much about performance or memory so just trying to keep my approach simple.

Here's some code:

in `main.cpp`

```
// FastLED Stuff
#include <FastLED.h>

#define WM_LEDS_PER_FACE 4
#define DATA_PIN 2
#define LED_TYPE WS2812
#define COLOR_ORDER GRB
CRGB leds[WM_LEDS_PER_FACE * 6];
uint8_t ledMap[WM_LEDS_PER_FACE * 6] = {
  0, 1, 2, 3, 
  4, 5, 12,  13,
  6, 7, 14, 15,
  8, 9, 16, 17,
  10, 11, 18, 19,
  20, 21, 22, 23
};

// Cube stuff
#include "Cube.h"

Cube cube(leds, WM_LEDS_PER_FACE, ledMap);

void setup() {
  cube.init(); // Set up all the faces
}

void loop() {
   cube.update();
}
```

in `Cube.h`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "Face.h"

class Cube
{

private:
    Face* faces = new Face[6];
    CRGB* leds = 0;
    uint8_t LEDsPerFace = 0;
    uint8_t totalLEDS = 0;
    uint8_t* ledMap = 0;

public:
    Cube(CRGB* fastLEDArray, uint8_t numLEDsPerFace, uint8_t* ledOrder) : leds(fastLEDArray), LEDsPerFace(numLEDsPerFace), ledMap(ledOrder) { totalLEDS = numLEDsPerFace * 6; }

    void init();
    void debug();
    void update();

private:
    void remapLEDs();
};
```

in `Cube.cpp`:

```
#include "Cube.h"

void Cube::init() {
    fill_solid(leds, totalLEDs, CRGB(0, 0, 0));
}


void Cube::update(){
    // draw some stuff using FastLED functions on `leds`
    // eg: fill_rainbow(leds, totalLEDs, 0);

    // remap here!
    if (ledMap > 0){ remapLEDs(); }
    FastLED.show();
}

void Cube::remapLEDs(){
    CRGB LEDcopy[totalLEDS];
    // Make a copy of the leds array
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < totalLEDS; ++i){
        LEDcopy[i] = leds[i];
    }

    // Overwrite the leds array with the new mapping
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < totalLEDS; ++i){
        leds[ledMap[i]] = LEDcopy[i];
    }
}
```

**Given that the above code appears fine on the surface, perhaps you could suggest a way that I could inspect the contents of my array before and after the mapping to try to get a better sense of what is going on.** Just writing out the contents of each element of `LEDcopy` and `leds` using Serial.print() gave me nonesense values like 12 and 9 as opposed to (at least) 24-bit words or (what I was expecting) some kind of 3-component struct (r, g, b).

There may be those of you tempted to post really slick, complicated one-liners that solve my problem in O(0) space in O(n) time, but please don't – I just need to understand the basics. Thanks!

Comment: I assume `totalLEDS` is set to a non-zero value somewhere? Could you provide a [mre]

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong in your mapping function code. We'll probably need a tad more background code to see how you're "assigning" those (presumably) class members in the constructor and how/where the arrays are defined in main.cpp. Are you using [this CRGB class](http://fastled.io/docs/3.1/struct_c_r_g_b.html)?

Comment: Also, that "obvious class stuff" that you've skipped may hold the secret key to unlock this mystery. :-)

Comment: e.g. a [mre] might look like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/o69jqsnEP) which seems to work correctly

Comment: 1. With pointers one problem is they do not carry length information. With current information I can only assume that the actual length does not match.

2. Also, `CRGB LEDcopy[totalLEDS];` is not standard c++. It is something called VLA – Variable Length Array and is implemented by some compilers. `totaLeds` must be available at compile time. 3. Instead of a remapping method I would simply write:  `CRGB& Cube::getLed(const int idx) { return leds[ledMap[idx]]; }`

Comment: @zdf Good call on the VLA - I missed that one!

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you for the comments! I've updated my code above to be more complete. I'm humbled by your willingness to take a look.

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks for taking a look. I've posted a more complete code example - thank you so much for offering to help.

Comment: @zdf thank you so much for your comments. I'll have to look up VLA so I understand why `CRGB LedCopy[totalLEDs]` is not standard c++. I appreciate your suggestion to just assign directly to the right index, but that would require rewriting/overloading large swaths of the FastLED convenience functions. My goal is to make the mapping "transparent" to the developer so they can just use FastLED as intended and have the mapping do a last-minute bait-and-switch. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @zdf I got it about the VLA now - i'm using a variable that's only available after compile time to initialize the size of the array. But how can we do otherwise and maintain proper OOP encapsulation? the Cube class should be able to work for any client software, so I can't hard-code a constant in cube.cpp. What's the downside to the VLA? Other than it might not work in come compilers?

Comment: You should use `std::vector<CRGB> LEDcopy(totalLEDs);` (if your platform supports `std::vector`, that is - not sure that Arduino does) and the rest of the code would work unchanged from the VLA.

Comment: @TomAuger 1. Given the fact that you are programming for Arduino you should probably not worry. Just keep it in mind. 2. I fail to see problems; maybe you should check the hw. I may be wrong - I’m on a phone.

Comment: Still seems to [work](https://godbolt.org/z/PqKs53cbq). What do you mean by `gets really messed up`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks for the example code - it does seem to work as advertised. this makes me question the CRGB struct (the real one in the library I mean). In terms of what is wrong - the LEDs indexed 6-7 when transposed turned on about 6 other LEDs, all set to the same (wrong) colour. So makes me think that the CRGB data is not transposing properly.

Comment: I've been trying more random stuff include `memcopy` (which was a total disaster) and `<vector>` (which made no difference). What I'm confused about is that whereas in `main.cpp`, `leds` is an array of CRGB values, in my class, `leds` is a POINTER to that array. So don't I need to dereference it or something so I can do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: 1. Google "array to pointer decay". 2. You should also check your schematics and the actual connections. Write a test program to individually test each led.

Comment: Thanks @zdf I did come across pointer decay in my research on this topic - are you saying that in my case CRGB* is actually the same thing as just saying `leds`? In terms of the wiring - it's rock solid and without the mapping code my LEDs light up sequentially perfectly. It's just the code that messes everything up significantly.

Comment: Incidentally @zdf I finally had to admit defeat and went with an approach similar to your suggestion - performing the remapping (using the same mapping index array) at the time of writing the LEDs as opposed to at the end. It works but I hate it because I've had to overload or copy all the built-in FastLED functions to add the mapping piece. I still want to crack this problem the right way some day because I know there's just some fundamental concept around memory usage that I'm not getting.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I wish I could just upload a video of it. If I write to LEDs 4, 5, 6 and 7 and then apply the mapping function, LEDs 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 and 15 (I think) all turn on, set to the same colour. Interestingly in my code the LEDs animate over time (by changing the brightness in a pulse) and although the colour is wrong, the brightness pulse is there. So somehow the bytes must still be lining up in some meaningful way.

Comment: @TomAuger I was just pointing you a search direction for your question regarding `leds` as an array or as a pointer.